# not getting correct data from firebase in ionic 3

Tags: typescript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3

I am working on an ionic app for backend I am using firebase,
I want to get the data from the firebase I have created an provider in which I have written a function as follow

```
loadData() {
    return this.afd.list('/vaccApp-f7771').valueChanges();
    }
```

I am calling this function in the constructor of an another page as follows

```
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams,public data: FirebaseProvider) {

   this.data.loadData().subscribe(k => {
   console.log(k);

  });
  }
```

but in console i am not getting correct data I am getting some array like this

```
[]length: 0__proto__: Array(0)concat: ƒ concat()constructor: ƒ Array()copyWithin: ƒ copyWithin()entries: ƒ entries()every: ƒ every()fill: ƒ fill()filter: ƒ filter()find: ƒ find()findIndex: ƒ findIndex()forEach: ƒ forEach()includes: ƒ includes()indexOf: ƒ indexOf()join: ƒ join()keys: ƒ keys()lastIndexOf: ƒ lastIndexOf()length: 0map: ƒ map()pop: ƒ pop()push: ƒ push()reduce: ƒ reduce()reduceRight: ƒ reduceRight()reverse: ƒ reverse()shift: ƒ shift()slice: ƒ slice()some: ƒ some()sort: ƒ sort()splice: ƒ splice()toLocaleString: ƒ toLocaleString()toString: ƒ toString()unshift: ƒ unshift()values: ƒ values()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): ƒ values()Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): {copyWithin: true, entries: true, fill: true, find: true, findIndex: true, …}__proto__: Object
```

any help??

Comment: Is 'vaccApp-f7771' the name of a node in your firebase database? Try setting it to '/' and updating your question.

Comment: i have done it its giving same

Comment: @AntonioGarcía any help plz

Comment: I'm going to need some more information. Could you show me the structure of your database? Also, is 'vaccApp-f7771' the name of your node or is it the name of your project?

Comment: its the name of my json in firebase